# Vector in Matlab + input

Tags: matlab, input, vector

I'm a beginner and trying to create a vector with same values but a few:

X = [4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 0, 0, 0] works for small vectors.

But if its a problem with hundreds of values it quickly runs out of hand.

Or this one that repeat same value into a vector: ones(1,14) * 0
But I have no idea how to get the 4, 6, 56 into that vector.

I would also want to learn how I can make an input commando while creating the vector 1 for example position 1 (which now is 4). Can I make a vector to I decide the value at that position?

P = input('Decide value for n=1 in X:');

Then i write P = input('Decide value for n=1 in X:');

I thought something like this could be useful but i dont know how to proceed

ones(1,14) * P,4

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want? `P=zeros(1,14);P([1 3 4 5])=[4 5 6 7]`. The values [4 5 6 7] can be taken from user as follows: `a=input('Enter an array with 4 elements:\n')`. Then the user has to enter: `[4 5 6 7]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use `ones(1,14)*0`, you can just use `zeros(1,14)`

To add in your specific values, you can set the value of the vector at an index directly:

```
X(1) = 4
X(5) = 6
X(11) = 56
```

To combine this with user input, try something along the lines of:

```
X(1) = input('Pick value for index 1 of X: ')
```

Note that this does not include any error checking of the input

Also, if you want to get the entire matrix from an input one value at a time, you don't even need to initialize the matrix first.  For example:

```
for i=1:10
    X(i) = input(strcat('Pick a number for index ', num2str(i), ' of X: '));
end
```

You could also just prompt the user for a vector instead

```
X = input('Enter a vector')
```